# Add timed ID3 metadata to HLS using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, id3, hls

For interactive video, I want to add timed ID3 metadata (different metadata at different times in the video) using FFmpeg but I couldn't find anything related to it on the internet.

I want to add custom metadata at a specific time like at 10 secs. Custom metadata will be something like:

question="When did COVID start?"
option1="2011"
option2="2019"

These metadata will be read & displayed by the frontend to the user. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added details specific to the problem.

Comment: How will the metadata be "read"? That is, what is the frontend that will display this metadata? And if you wish to display text, why not use subtitles?